# Custom Components Sorting based on required Ordering

Tags: android, kotlin

Trying to sort the custom components on defined order, and other subjects should be after that desired order: Like if there is any other subject except the defined List ie "GK" then it should be on last position etc.

However I am getting Null Pointer Exception due to subject is not defined in the requireList if scheduleCommandList have the subject which is not in requiredList. How can I overcome this?

Desired Order List is Below:

```
private val requiredList: HashMap<String, Int> = hashMapOf(
        "Maths" to 0,
        "Physics" to 1,
        "Science" to 2,
           )
```

Sorting function to sort the List:

```
private fun sortCommandList(scheduleCommandList: ArrayList<BaseComponent>): ArrayList<BaseComponent> {
              val comparator = Comparator { o1: BaseComponent, o2: BaseComponent ->
                return@Comparator requiredList[o1.name]!! - requiredList[o2.name]!!
            }
             val copy = arrayListOf<BaseComponent>().apply { addAll(scheduleCommandList) }
        copy.sortWith(comparator)
        return copy
    }
```

Comment: What if there are multiple components that are not on required list? Should they be sorted in some order or left with random sorting?

Comment: @broot current scenerio is that to left them on random order if they not belongs to requiredList or the actual order they are in. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you understand the problem correctly. If an item is not present in `requiredList` then you still try to compare their required positions and this causes `NullPointerException`. Remember that you should use `!!` only in cases when you are sure there can't be a null. In this case null is possible and we have to handle it somehow. The easiest is to replace it with `Int.MAX_VALUE` which places the item at the end. Also, this code can be really much simpler:

```
private fun sortCommandList(scheduleCommandList: List<BaseComponent>): List<BaseComponent> {
    return scheduleCommandList.sortedBy { requiredList[it.name] ?: Int.MAX_VALUE }
}
```

It can be even better to create this utility as extension function:

```
private fun List<BaseComponent>.mySort(): List<BaseComponent> {
    return sortedBy { requiredList[it.name] ?: Int.MAX_VALUE }
}
```

Then we can simplify the name of the function, because it is implicit that it is used to sort `BaseComponent` objects.

Comment: It's As expected :)